# How is the data generated for a double in webassembly?

Tags: webassembly

In Webassembly the following:

```
double x = 1;
```

Is analog to this WAST:

```
(module
  (table 0 anyfunc)
  (memory $0 1)
  (data (i32.const 16) "\00\00\00\00\00\00\f0?")
  (export "memory" (memory $0))
)
```

I already figured out how it works with integers (by using hex numbers) but what I see for doubles isnt the usual hex im familiar with.

For example an integer of 15 is equivalent to: "\0f\00\00\00" which I understand but how does it work for doubles. What kind of hex is it and what defines the offset inside the data section?

I am using https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/ for testing purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebAssembly uses IEEE-754 to encode `f32` and `f64`.

The data section is being initialized with `"\00\00\00\00\00\00\f0?"` which is ASCII-encoding. That's just what the author of s-expressions chose to use, in the actual binary it's encoded as 4 or 8 bytes (for `f32` versus `f64`). We could also use hex-float as C / C++ support, we just need a lossless encoding (and hex-float is lossy with NaNs). Another option is base64, or raw hex, or whatever. The data section doesn't care what datatype it contains: in the binary format it's all just bytes. So we're not really encoding floating-point values or integers, just bytes.

This decodes to hex `3FF000000000`. Why? There's a `?` at the end, its ASCII value is `3F`. Then you have all the escaped ASCII values which don't have nicer representations so the escape encoding is used. It's really not a great representation!

What does this mean? Try out [this tool](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/) to understand IEEE-754 encoding!

```
Binary64: 3FF0000000000000
Status  Sign [1]    Exponent [11]   Significand [52]
Normal  0 (+)       01111111111 (0) 1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (1.0)
```

So sign is positive, exponent is 0, and significand is 1.0. That's value `1.0` in IEEE-754.

Comment: You are a genius. Thank you.